# Is there a way to see what a wildcard pattern is receiving during a match in Scala?

Tags: scala, case, wildcard, match, actor

When doing pattern matching in an Akka or Scala Actor, is there a way to see what the match was NOT (i.e.) what is being evaluated by the wildcard _?  Is there a simple way to see which message is being processed from the mailbox that it can't find a match for?

```
def receive = {
  case A =>
  case B =>
  case C =>
  ...
  case _ =>
    println("what IS the message evaluated?")
}
```

Thanks,

Bruce

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just define variable like this:

```
def receive = {
  case A =>
  case B =>
  case C =>
  ...
  case msg =>
    println("unsupported message: " + msg)
}
```

You can even assign names to the messages that you are matching with `@`:

```
def receive = {
  case msg @ A => // do someting with `msg`
  ...
}
```

Comment: This won't handle the _ case though, and without it, the match won't be exhaustive.  I'm interested in doing an exhaustive match, and to find out what the case not being match is, no matter what it is.

Comment: @BruceFerguson: in this case `case msg =>` means exactly the same as `case _ =>`. The only difference is that you can actually use `msg` in the body of the case.

Comment: @tenshi.  I tried it, and it works.  Thanks again for your help.  Cheers, Bruce

Answer (score 3):

The "correct" way to do this in Akka is to override the "unhandled"-method, do what you want, and either delegate to the default behavior or replace it.

http://akka.io/api/akka/2.0-M4/#akka.actor.Actor

As for pattern matching in general, just match on anything, and bind it to a name, so you can refer to it:

```
x match {
  case "foo" => whatever
  case otherwise => //matches anything and binds it to the name "otherwise", use that inside the body of the match
}
```